# Real-Time Automated Amazon S3 Backup for Windows

Tags: backup, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

I'm looking for a service I can configure in Windows 7 that will run in the background to monitor selected file system(s) for changes, and immediately push those changes in a lazy fashion to my Amazon S3 bucket.

I know there are a lot of tools out there that provide scheduled backups, but I'm looking for something more granular.

Encrypted backup is a plus, but not necessarily a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another option to backup data to cloud storage powered by Amazon S3. Check out [CloudBerry Backup](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup)  . It is one time fee and the rest what you pay for Amazon S3. Besides, there is no proprietary data format and you can access your data using other Amazon s3 tools. Supports all Amazon S3 regions and Reduced Redundancy Storage. it can even map S3 storage as a local disk

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Crashplan Personal](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/crashplan-plus.html).  According to the ad copy, it does continuous, minute-by-minute backup, encryption, and has a cloud option.

EDIT:  Actually it looks like Crashplan does not support S3 as a back end, so this isn't a great answer to the specific question.  Crashplan still looks like a good solution to the continuous backup requirement though.

Comment: Crashplan Personal is discontinued as of October 2018.